# Websockets over Protocol buffers(protobufs)/binary vs JSON/text performance

Tags: json, performance, websocket, binary, protocol-buffers

Are protobufs sent as binary data over WebSockets faster than JSON sent as text data over WebSockets? As on paper, this seems to be true, even taking into account the small overhead generated by handling bytes on both sides. Did anyone really had a chance to try this and has some concrete results? Thanks!

Comment: this is an impossible question to ask/answer without specifics; for example, for many "smallish" messages: *it won't matter* - the key performance factor will be network performance, and it'll be a single packet of data either way; yes protobuf will be a bit smaller (often quite a bit), but for many smallish messages: it really won't matter. JSON is obviously much *simpler* to work with from a browser. But no, I haven't ever done the hard work to prove this completely.

Comment: https://nilsmagnus.github.io/post/proto-json-sizes/ this article really intrigued me, and it shows that smaller messages are actually not "quite a bit" smaller in protobufs than in json, but actually a lot smaller, really interesting

Comment: Afaik, protobuf messages will always take less space than their equivalent JSON (maybe with the exception of things like some number literals, etc.), so sending them will always be faster. Another question is how long it takes to encode/decode them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I've made a small project for researching this and I've got some results. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/adrianbrad/websockets-protobufs-json-race/blob/master/README.md), you can find more information in the **README** and in the `results` package.

To answer the question; **YES**, protocol buffers are faster than JSON over 100_000 messages sent as ping pong (no processing over them except marshalling and unmarshalling). But the difference is not as notable as I would have expected.